# Symfony2 authentication/login using email instead of username

Tags: symfony, authentication, doctrine, entity

I've been trying to create a login form today using Symfony2 where a user can login using their email address and password. I've had lot's of problems and in the end realised it will only work if I have a `$username` property in my `AdminUser` entity class. I've tried to use email instead of username where possible so can someone please explain why `$username` is required or where I have gone wrong? Also, in my `login.html.twig` file I am still using `_username` rather than `_email` if that makes any difference? My code is below (I've removed some getters and setters which aren't applicable):

AdminUser Entity:

```
namespace XXX\WebsiteBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* AdminUser
*
* @ORM\Table(name="admin_user",indexes={@ORM\Index(name="indexes", columns={"deleted"})})
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
*/
class AdminUser implements UserInterface
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=45)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=45, unique=true)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $salt;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="enabled", type="integer", options={"default" = 0})
 */
private $enabled;

/**
 * @var string[] $roles
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="array")
 */
private $roles = array();

private $username;


/**
 * Gets the username.
 *
 * @return string The username.
 */
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * Erases the user credentials.
 */
public function eraseCredentials()
{

}


/**
 * Returns the roles granted to the user.
 *
 * <code>
 * public function getRoles()
 * {
 *     return array('ROLE_USER');
 * }
 * </code>
 *
 * Alternatively, the roles might be stored on a ``roles`` property,
 * and populated in any number of different ways when the user object
 * is created.
 *
 * @return Role[] The user roles
 */
public function getRoles() {
    return $this -> roles;
}

/**
 * Set the roles of the user
 *
 * @var string[] $roles
 *
 * @return \XXX\WebsiteBundle\Entity\User this
 */
public function setRoles(array $roles) {
    $this -> roles = $roles;

    return $this;
}



}
```

My `security.yml` file is:

> jms_security_extra:
>       secure_all_services: false
>       expressions: true

```
security:
encoders:
    XXX\WebsiteBundle\Entity\AdminUser: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    main_provider:
        entity: { class: XXX\WebsiteBundle\Entity\AdminUser, property: email }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    admin_firewall:
        pattern:  ^/admin.*
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path:  /admin/login
            check_path:  /admin/login_check

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login.*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin.*, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: You have to have a getUsername() method in AdminUser just to satisfy the user interface requirement.  But it can return email like you have it.  The property: email should be all you have to do.  You can look in the EntityUserProvider class just to verify what is happening.  Maybe start with a fresh install?  Sometimes I mess things up while trouble shooting.

Answer (score 12):

I guess you should change property with email and also you can change the _username parameter with anything you want by:

```
entity:
            entity:
                class:               SecurityBundle:User
                property:            username
```

and

```
firewalls
    form_login:
        username_parameter: _username
```

may be you should have a look at [security configuration document](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/reference/configuration/security.html)

Comment: works for me, the only "piece" left it's getUsername() method due to UserInterface interface.

Comment: works under securty.yml -> firewalls ->main ->form_login: ->username_parameter: email and of corse input name='email'

Answer (score 2):

```
firewalls:
 main:
  form_login: 
    username_parameter: _email
```

All of your code is correct you only need to make a little change in the security.yml file. just add the username_parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda hackish, but you could remove the username field from your registration forms, and in your user entity, do this:

```
public function setEmail($email) 
{
    $this->email = $email;
    $this->username = $email;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I suppose, however I'm trying to learn the best practices and prevent much hacking. I did find this page - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#authenticating-someone-with-a-custom-entity-provider would I have to create a AdminUserRepository?

Answer (score 0):

Try and use [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle).

It has a default [feature](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/logging_by_username_or_email.md) for users to be able to login with their username or email fields.

Comment: The FOSUserBundle doesn't allow login by email only. It allows username only and if configured username or email. Just thought I'd make that clear to those seeking an answer to this question.

Comment: If the question was about the different ways to implement user authentication, this would be a valid answer. But user's problem is not related to mentioned bundle.